# BeanConfig (or similar?) in Swagger 2.0 (OpenApi 3.0)

Tags: java, migration, swagger, openapi

I am currently migrating our API docs (which were Swagger 1.5) to Swagger 2.0 (OpenApi 3.0)

The API docs are Swagger docs which get generated with java annotations using maven packages `swagger-annotations` and `swagger-jaxrs`. I have already updated the pom.xml with new versions so it looks like:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

And also all the old annotations are replaced with the new ones (which change quite a lot) and looks fine.

The thing is we were using a `BeanConfig` to define the docs general config and auto-scan all the REST resources so the documentation got generated automatically at `/swagger.json`.

The **problem** is I can't find the "new way" of doing such thing as creating a BeanConfig and auto-scan the resources so everything gets generated at `/swagger.json` or `/openapi.json` (maybe now is something like OpenAPIDefinition?)

If somebody could point me to the right direction I would be very grateful...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research, I could find some documentation about it in their [Github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration#jax-rs-application) for JAX-RS application, so the result is something similar to what I was doing but now instead of using a `BeanConfig`, it uses `OpenAPI` and `Info`:

```
@ApplicationPath("/sample")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        super();
        OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
        Info info = new Info()
            .title("Swagger Sample App bootstrap code")
            .description("This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger " +
                    "at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, " +
                    "you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.")
            .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
            .contact(new Contact()
                    .email("apiteam@swagger.io"))
            .license(new License()
                    .name("Apache 2.0")
                    .url("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"));

        oas.info(info);
        SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
            .openAPI(oas)
            .prettyPrint(true)
            .resourcePackages(Stream.of("io.swagger.sample.resource").collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        try {
            new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                .servletConfig(servletConfig)
                .application(this)
                .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                .buildContext(true);
        } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: NB: it's `io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info` - not to be confused with the annotation of the same name!

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, adding the imports to java snippets is a good practice to be honest, will do so from now on :)

Comment: So with all this, is something supposed to generate the swagger.json? I thought that was the point of the original question right? I used this code and no swagger.json file is getting generated for me

Comment: yes, a url serving the swagger docs is generated automatically

Answer (score 5):

Though OP has answered their own question, but adding a few more details for people like me who landed on this post as I wanted to migrate from swagger 1.x to swagger 2.0 (openAPI 3) and needed complete config.

(This example is for embedded jetty)

```
// Jetty configuration

// ContextHandlerCollection contexts

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/api");
context.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ImmutableSet.<Class<?>>builder()
                                                                .add(MyRestService.class)
                                                                .build());
resourceConfig.registerClasses(OpenApiResource.class,AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource.class); // for swagger, this will cerate openapi.json at <host>/api/openapi.json
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/*");
contexts.addHandler(context);
```

If you need to change default swagger config, that can be done by what OP has described in their answer:

```
OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
        Info info = new Info()
            .title("Swagger Sample App bootstrap code")
            .description("This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger " +
                    "at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, " +
                    "you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.")
            .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
            .contact(new Contact()
                    .email("apiteam@swagger.io"))
            .license(new License()
                    .name("Apache 2.0")
                    .url("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"));

        oas.info(info);
        SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
            .openAPI(oas)
            .prettyPrint(true)
            .resourcePackages(Stream.of("io.swagger.sample.resource").collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        try {
            new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                .servletConfig(servletConfig)
                .application(this)
                .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                .buildContext(true);
        } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

Comment: How do you put the two examples here together?  IE Where do you get a ServletConfig or the contexts object?

Comment: That object would be part of your jetty config. Nothing specific to swagger.

Comment: @tryingToLearn I am using Jetty 11 (which is Jakarta EE 9)  and added required dependencies but not able to find `GzipFilter.class` for `context.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));`

Comment: @AniruddhaTekade you can ignore that line.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler solution for the above requirement.

```
import io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Contact;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


@OpenAPIDefinition(
    info =
        @Info(
            title = "Sample rest service",
            version = "1.0.0",
            description = "Sample rest service",
            contact =
                @Contact(
                    url = "https://jira2.cerner.com/projects/Dey",
                    name = "ADey")))
public class SampleRestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
  public SampleRestApplication() {
    register(OpenApiResource.class);
  }
}
```

your service will load your API spec at `/openApi.yaml|json`.

Comment: I am also trying to configure swagger-core for openapi-3. Any idea about how would I integrate into Jetty 11?

Comment: This works if the values are constant - in which case it's simpler still to put them into a `openapi-configuration.yaml` file!

Comment: This is glassfish-specific...

Answer (score 0):

Another variant on the same theme. You can package up your openAPI config generation logic into a stand-alone class like so:

```java
    @Provider
    public class SwaggerInfoBlackMagic implements Feature {
        @Context ServletConfig config;
        @Context Application app;

        @Override
        public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
            //The aim here is to force construction of a (convincing) OpenApiContext before swagger does!
            //This has been lifted from BaseOpenApiResource
            String ctxId = getContextIdFromServletConfig(config);
            try {
                OpenApiContext ctx = new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                        .servletConfig(config)
                        .application(app)
                        //Might need more of these depending on your setup..
                        //.resourcePackages(resourcePackages)
                        //.configLocation(configLocation)
                        .openApiConfiguration(getOpenApi())
                        .ctxId(ctxId)
                        .buildContext(true); //this also stores the instance statically
            } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return true;
        }


        private OpenAPIConfiguration getOpenApi() {...}
    }
```

Then whenever you need it you can simply add:

```java
jersey().register(SwaggerInfoBlackMagic.class);
```

It's the same as the above but slightly tidier.