# Swagger open api 3.0 update

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

We are using swagger annotations to generate swagger doc in our java ee project.I am updating swagger version from 1.6.x to 2.10.x which includes updating to open api 3.0

Earlier we used following code to configure swagger.

```
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
Swagger swagger = beanConfig.getSwagger();
beanConfig.setHost(swagger.getHost());
beanConfig.setBasePath("/v1/");
beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.pkg");
beanConfig.setScan(true);
```

I am not able to find its replacement. I am adding @OpenAPIDefinition on top of configuration class but no help.Can someone point me towards any useful link or its replacement annotations?
Thanks

Comment: Probably can be helpful [BeanConfig (or similar?) in Swagger 2.0 (OpenApi 3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185836/beanconfig-or-similar-in-swagger-2-0-openapi-3-0)

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration) regarding Swagger 2.0 configuration.

Instead of `BeanConfig`, you need to use `OpenAPI` and `Info`

Example from the documentation:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/sample")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        super();
        OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
        Info info = new Info()
                .title("Swagger Sample App bootstrap code")
                .description("This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger " +
                        "at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, " +
                        "you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.")
                .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
                .contact(new Contact()
                        .email("apiteam@swagger.io"))
                .license(new License()
                        .name("Apache 2.0")
                        .url("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"));

        oas.info(info);
        SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
                .openAPI(oas)
                .prettyPrint(true)
                .resourcePackages(Stream.of("io.swagger.sample.resource").collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        try {
            new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder()
                    .servletConfig(servletConfig)
                    .application(this)
                    .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                    .buildContext(true);
        } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```